# Gamma Function Converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm reading on pg 160 of  Complex Analysis by Stein, and I am having trouble understanding the argument below -- it is intuitively plausible, but I don't see it rigorously.

For s > 0, $\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{s-1}dt$

The integral converges for each positive s because near $t = 0$ the function $t^{s-1}$ is integrable, and for $t$ large the convergence is guaranteed by the exponential decay of the integrand.

Comment: Write $\Gamma(s)=\int_0^b e^{-t}t^{s-1}\,dt+\int_b^\infty e^{-t}t^{s-1}\,dt$, then consider each integral separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on a comment, if you consider $\int_0^b e^{-t}t^{s-1} dt$ for finite $b$ then you get that the integral is less than $\int_0^b t^{s-1} dt$, so the integral exists and is finite. Then when you consider $\int_b^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{s-1} dt$, you can use the fact that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^{s-1}e^{-t}}{e^{-t/2}} = 0$ and then bound the integral for sufficiently large $b$ by the integral $\int_b^{\infty} e^{-t/2}dt$, which you know converges.