# Show the divergence of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt k (\ln k)^2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I'm attempting to understand how the following sum behaves for different values of $p$ and $q$:
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{ k^q (\ln k)^p} $$I think I have figured out every case, except when $q \in (0,1)$ and $p>1. $ To determine what to do, I gave concrete values to $p$ and $q$. Namely, $q=\frac{1}{2}$, and $p=2$. But I still can't figure out how to prove the behavior of the series. Using Wolfram Alpha, I know that the series below diverges, but I don't know how to prove it. Does anyone have any insight to showing either the general case above or the more concrete case below? Thanks in advance.

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt k (\ln k)^2} $$

Comment: Can you apply the integral test?

Comment: I tried, but my if I set $u = \ln k$, and $du=1/k$, it doesn't quite work properly. Perhaps a different integration strategy would be better?

Comment: That should be the correct approach.  Could you show what you get after the substitution?

Comment: Are you referring to the general case or the specific one?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: This is an example of a *Bertrand's series*: $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n^{\alpha}\ln^{\beta}n}$. You can see the complete result in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227199/does-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-lnn2-converge-or-diver/2227311#2227311).

Comment: I don't get it, how do you split Blakes?

Comment: -_-      .............

Comment: @simplybeautifulart Cauchy's Condensation Test works well here.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the original time that I posted this, many of these answers did not make complete sense to me, so I figured that I would post my own answer to this question that would have made sense to me back then.

We will solve the general case, when $q \in (0,1)$ and $p>1$. To solve this problem, we will have to use both the direct comparison test and the integral test.

Let $\displaystyle a_k = \frac{1}{k^q (\ln k)^p}$ and $\displaystyle b_k = \frac{1}{k\ln k}$. Arguably, the hardest part of this problem is understanding that for sufficiently large $k$, $a_k > b_k$. To prove this, we take the limit of their quotient.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k \ln k}{k^q (\ln k)^p} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^{1-q}}{(\ln k)^{p-1}}$$

Because $k^\alpha \gg (\ln k)^\beta$ for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, we know that the above limit is equal to $\infty$. Therefore, there must exist an $N$ such that for $k>N$, $k\ln k > k^q (\ln k)^p$. Thus, we conclude that for sufficiently large $k$,
$$k \ln k > k^q (\ln k)^p \iff \frac{1}{k\ln k} < \frac{1}{k^q (\ln k)^p} \iff b_k < a_k$$

Now that we have that out of the way, if we can prove that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty b_k$ diverges, then $\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k$ must diverge as well by the direct comparison test.

To prove that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty b_k$ diverges, we use the integral test.

$$\begin{align*} 
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln x} dx &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_2^b \frac{1}{x \ln x}dx, \qquad u = \ln x, \quad du = \frac{1}{x}dx \\
&=\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{\ln 2}^{\ln b} \frac{1}{u}du \\
&= \lim_{b \to \infty} \Big[\ln|u|\Big]_{\ln2}^{\ln b}\\
&= \lim_{b \to \infty} \Big(\ln\big|\ln b\big| - \ln\big|\ln2\big|\Big)\\
&=\infty
\end{align*}$$

Since the improper integral diverges, the associated sum $\sum b_k$ must diverge as well from the integral test. Therefore, we may conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^q (\ln k)^p}$ diverges for $q\in (0,1)$ and $p >1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Informally**:

Actually, $\ln k$ grows slower than any positive power of $k$: for any $\alpha>0$ there is an $n$ such that

$$k>n\implies\ln k<k^\alpha$$

as, taking the derivative, $k^{-1}$ grows slower than $k^{\alpha-1}$.

Then you can replace $q$ by $q+\alpha<1$ and drop the $\ln$ factor, and the resulting series is bounded below by the harmonic one.

---

More about this:

In a way, $\ln k=k^0$. Indeed,

$$\ln k=\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{k^\alpha-1}\alpha.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the general case, use the integral test for series. Observe that $$\sum \frac{1}{k^p\ln(k)^q} \approx \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p\ln(x)^q} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(p-1)u}}{u^q}du$$ It should be easier to deduce what values of $p$ and $q$ lead to convergence.

Comment: I believe the exponents on this are flipped. Does that change the assessment at all?

Comment: I switched the indices on accident but the analysis should be the same

Comment: How would I consider integrating the last integral, with arbitrary powers? Integration by parts seems like the only option, but it looks awful.

Comment: The integration by parts doesn't look to bad. If you need help with seemingly long integration by parts problems, look up the DI method on youtube, particularly on blackpenredpen's channel

Comment: @BlakeSplitter ask yourself if the integrand approaches zero when $p <1$.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson: I looked at the DI method on Youtube, and while informative and useful, I don't think it can be practically applied to this case. None of the stops would be achieved, since $p$ and $q$ need not be integers.

Comment: The argument is very similar to the one in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496679/gamma-function-converges

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the following: $\left(\ln k\right)^2 < \sqrt[3]{k}$ for large enough $k \ge 2$. And this amounts to: $\ln k < k^{\frac{1}{6}}$. The ratio $\dfrac{k^{1/6}}{\ln k} \to +\infty$ as $k \to \infty$. Thus starting at $k_0$ on ward, $k^{1/6} > \ln k \implies \ln k - k^{1/6} < 0, k \ge k_0$.

Answer (score 1):

From Cauchy's Condensation Test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log^2(n)}$ is convergent if anf only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n/2}}{n^2\log^2(2)}$ converges.  Since the latter series diverges (the general terms do not approach $0$), the series of interest diverges likewise.

Answer (score 0):

The key fact is that
$\dfrac{\ln x}{x^c}
\to 0
$
as $x \to \infty$
for any $c > 0$.

So show this,
start with
$\dfrac{\ln x}{x}
\to 0
$
as $x \to \infty$.
Then
$\dfrac{\ln x^c}{x^c}
\to 0
$
as $x \to \infty$.
But
$\dfrac{\ln x^c}{x^c}
=\dfrac{c\ln x}{x^c}
\to 0
$.

Here is an easy way to show that
$\dfrac{\ln x}{x}
\to 0
$.

$\ln(x)
=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}
\le\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{1/2}}
=\dfrac{x^{1/2}-1}{1/2}
\lt 2x^{1/2}
$
so
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\le \dfrac{2}{x^{1/2}}
\to 0
$.

You can also
show it directly
by a modification of
this last proof.

For any $c > d > 0$
and $x > 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x)
&=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&\lt\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{1-d}}
\qquad\text{since } t > t^{1-d}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{d}-1}{d}\\
&<\dfrac{x^{d}-1}{d}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^c}
&\le \dfrac{x^{d-c}}{d}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{dx^{c-d}}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$